# I'm trying to implement a Xamarin local image on my App, but it's not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add a local image in my Xamarin app, but it's not working. Do you know what I could've have missed?

I have added the  XAML and c# code but that still does not work.

```
 XAML -  <Image x:Name="Background_Image" Source="backgroundimage.png"/>


C# - var image = new Image { Source = "backgroundimage.png" };
```

I have followed the proper practices to a tee from the Xamarin Images documentation, but it's still not working. Link to Xamarin Documentation on Images - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#Local_Images)

I have made sure the file name is

- All in lowercase,
- The build action is AndroidResource of the image
- The image has been placed in the Resources/drawable folder.

Which are all the conventions you must follow, but it doesn't seem to work.

The image's file size is 1.28mb and resolution is 1920x1080 if that matters. I have tested with a much smaller 4KB image but does not work either. 
I am using the Xamarin Live Player to show the app, the phone uses API 19, Android 4.4

I apologise if this is a duplicate, but I have read many topics here but I have not been able to fix it.

Comment: You don't need XAML and C#, just one or the other

Comment: Watch your application output logs closely, Android outputs a lot or errors there. There might be something about the image being too big.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked, I can't seem to find an error in the logs, but I forgot to note I did test use a smaller image in the KB's but this still does not show up either

Comment: I'd try a device or emulator, it may be an issue with the Live Player

Comment: Try setting the `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand`  and  `Aspect="AspectFit"`  What kind of container is the image in?  I'm assuming "drawble" is a typo.

Comment: It's just in an StackLayout, and I've tried those to no avail. And yes it was just a typo.

Comment: Your were correct, it's an issue with the Live Player, as I've built it with the Android Emulator, and it's displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to be  a issue or limitation with Xamarin's own Live player.  I have launched the App with the Android Emulator and the Image is displaying, I'll report it as a bug.